# Long-term potentiations that last for a lifetime

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, learning, neuroplasticity

One reads more often than not that

- [long-term potentiation has been reported to last for as long as several **weeks**](https://dnalc.cshl.edu/view/1209-How-Long-is-LTP-.html)
- [LTP is persistent, lasting from several minutes to many **months**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_potentiation#Properties)

and most sources seem to explain mechanisms of LTP that just last as long - from hours to days to weeks to months. Only rarely it is explicitly mentioned that such-and-such LTP lasts for years or a lifetime, and most authors seem to hesitate to make such claims.

But there **are** memories (and learned skills) that can be retrieved many years and even decades later, even though not (consciously) used in the meantime.

I have no idea how this kind of "*really* long-term potentiation" is explained. Three options come to my mind:

1. The long-term potentiated synapses and the "memories" related to them have actually been *used* in the meantime (just "unconsciously" or in completely different contexts) and thus been re-newed and re-strenghtened every now and then.
2. They degraded but have been re-newed without having been used, but by some other mechanisms than "normal" LTP.
3. They actually *did* last for such a long time (i.e. didn't degrade) - and the authors just hesitated to claim it (because they could not prove directly).

Is one of these three explanations the correct one, or is there another one?

Comment: No time for an answer but some dendritic spines live long enough to sustain memories that can last for as long as the animal lives ([Yang et al 2009](https://doi.org/10.1038/nature08577)). Each time a memory is recalled, it is also reshaped --potentially strengthened, attenuated, or otherwise altered.

Comment: @vkehayas. Hi, Vassilis, great  to hear from you again! The explanatory problem is that a memory or skill (as a holistic entity) may be un-recalled for decades and thus not reshaped. It's only the synapses involved in the memory that are re-strengthened, attenuated, or otherwise altered - just by being part of many other memories that **were** recalled. Does this picture make sense? (Alternatively one might consider that the memory itself actually **was** recalled, but unconsciously, maybe in dreams?)